# error message while converting pdf to jpg file

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert a PDF file to jpg file, this is what I was doing and the related error message. What are the reasons for this kind of error?

```
magick convert -density 600 C:\Users\Desktop\temp.pdf C:\Users\Desktop\temp.jpg
convert: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r600x600"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/ugwz/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-36562c7WhZLZFMM6%d" "-fC:/Users/ugwz/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-3656VktS46lP2HwZ" "-fC:/Users/ugwz/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-3656xOHiogtkf3t5"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/459.
convert: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.
' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/796.
convert: no images defined `C:\Users\Desktop\temp.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3275.
```

To validate the existence of original file location, here is the output

```
C:\Users\Desktop>dir temp.pdf
 Volume in drive C is Global Information Link
 Volume Serial Number is 6646-37D4

 Directory of C:\Users\Desktop

07/10/2018  01:55 PM           175,108 temp.pdf
               1 File(s)        175,108 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  12,942,802,944 bytes free
```

Comment: have you checked if the path is definitely correct? the error message suggests the file you are trying to convert isn't at the path you have specified

Comment: I checked, it is there

Comment: and your output path is correct? i.e., it is a valid path?

Comment: yes, both the original file and converted file are placed on the desktop

Comment: I just modified the post, to show the existence of original file

Comment: Try `identify C:\Users\Desktop\temp.pdf`, and see if it's the same error. It could be a corrupt document.

Comment: Are you sure that Ghostscript is installed and Imagemagick can find it? Does `convert -version` list gs or gslib? Also note that in Imagemagick 7, convert is replace by magick. So do not specify both as magick convert; otherwise, you may get Imagemagick 6 results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe"
```

This told me that I didn't have [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) installed. Installing it (and restarting my Windows console) solved the problem.